# Variable auto_prepend_file?

Tags: php

Okay, I suck at titling my questions XD If anyone has a better title, please edit!

Anyway, I have this in my php.ini file:

```
auto_prepend_file = ./include/startup.php
auto_append_file = ./include/shutdown.php
```

startup.php looks something like this:

```
<?php
chdir(__DIR__."/..");
require("include/db.php");
// more setup stuff here
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "AJAX") { // yup, custom HTTP method :p
    // parse file_get_contents("php://input")
}
else {
    $output_footer = true;
    require("include/header.php");
}
```

shutdown.php goes something like this:

```
<?php
if( isset($output_footer)) require("include/footer.php");
```

Now, on to the main problem.

---

header.php includes the line `<title>My shiny new site</title>`. I want that title to depend on the page that is currently being viewed. At the moment, I have some ugly hack that involves JavaScript:

```
document.title = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].textContent;
```

Obviously, this is not ideal! Any suggestions on how to adjust the title when said title is being output as a result of an auto_prepend_file?

Comment: Why use `auto_prepend_file` at all? Especially when you have issue with dynamic content? (while this directive designed to be static)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should use the append and prepend functionality like that But that's just my  opinion.

Why not create `header.php` to allow for a variable title text. And drop the prepend and append scripts completely

```
<title><?php echo (isset($title)) ? $title : 'default title'; ?></title>
```

And whenever you need a title tag.

```
$title = "some title";
require("include/header.php");
```